# Can I send an email to one person with several row of DE in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

For example, I have a DE with some rows. And it looks like this

| customer_name | email | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | abc@gmail.com | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| abc | abc@gmail.com | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| abc | abc@gmail.com | 3 | 3 | 4 |
| abc | abc@gmail.com | 1 | 4 | 5 |
| xyz | xyz@gmail.com | 2 | 5 | 3 |
| xyz | xyz@gmail.com | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| mno | mno@gmail.com | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| mno | mno@gmail.com | 8 | 3 | 4 |

For now, if I send an email through Journey with this DE, every row has been sent. so that customer "abc" has received 4 mails for each row. (1,2,3) for first mail, (2,5,2) for second mail...

But what I want is each customer received just one mail with col1, col2, col3
For example, what "abc" has received looks like this

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 |

and what "xyz" has received looks like this

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The following below is not a full solution but provides enough direction to achieve the outcome.

1. The customer is receiving multiple emails, but you want each customer to receive just one?

Then, first you need a send DE source where it has only unique contact rows.

-> Create a separate DE where it only has unique contact rows and use it as the send data source:

Reference: [SQL DISTINCT statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

2. You want the email sent to the customer to have attribute values linking to that customer?

-> Use your original DE as the reference source, make a lookup to that DE source and pull the values from there.

Reference: [LookupRows](https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows/)